# Run Python script from rest API in django

Tags: python, django

I have a script file (.py) which I need to run in my POST API requests. The scripts have few input parameters as well.

I am able to follow the link: https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html and now I am successfully able to run a script from the shell.

```
python manage.py runscript scriptName --script-args arg1 arg2
```

But now, I want to run the same script with arguments in my API where arguments will be posted from the POST requests.
I found that I can use subprocess for it. But it's not working.

Below is the code I am trying to run:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(['scriptName', arg1, arg2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = cmd.communicate()
```

On executing the above code the script file opens up in the browser.

**NOTE:** The script which I am executing contains Machine Learning Code.

Please help me out and let me know what I am doing wrong here. I also need the output of the script to return as a response.

Comment: what is the error showing on console?

Comment: @NakulNarayanan It is not executing the script but opening the script file in the browser.

Comment: I didn't understand..

Comment: Do you need any access to the database, or any other data from the API rest besides the parameters?

Comment: Why are you running a python script as a subprocess, rather than just executing the code directly in your program?

Comment: @Ruben No. I don't need any database access.

Comment: @JohanL.. This was the approach I found. If you have any other approach please share.

Comment: But why not just import it and call it from the view?

Comment: Have you considered using async task queues for this job ? You can check [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Comment: okay @fxgx. Let me check this one out.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working code

**DjangoProject/Project/view.py**

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
import os

class MyView(ListAPIView):
    def post(self,request):
        message = self.request.POST.get('message','')
        os.system('python cout.py '+message)
        return Response(
            {
                "Status":True
            }
        )
```

my python script on the root django folder

**DjangoProject/cout.py**

```
import sys
print("Python : ",sys.argv[1])
```

with post man you can send a post request with form data 'message'
and you can see that message on your console

Example:
In postman

```
message = hi jasir
```

In your console :

```
Python : hi jasir
```

Comment: a minimalist approach. nice